# BitBucket will not allow me to clone my git repository to my own directory

Tags: git, bitbucket

When I try to clone my bitbucket repositories into the directory I specify and I like, it tells me "permission denied" while trying to clone. However, when I use the default directory to clone into it works just fine. Does anyone know? I've never had this issue before, I've always been able to clone into my own custom directories

Comment: Are you sure that you have permission? Does this directory on disk C:?

Comment: bitbucket has no control over and no knowledge of your local directories.  If you are getting a permission denied error it suggests you should be looking at the permissions of your local directories.